# How to construct this Matrix

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, list-manipulation, input

A $4\times 4$ identity matrix $\mathbb{I}$ can be written as $\mathbb I=\delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}$.

To construct this matrix, I wrote

```
Table[KroneckerDelta[i, j] KroneckerDelta[k, l], {i, 2}, {j, 2}, {k, 2}, {l, 2}] // MatrixForm
```

But this is quite not in the regular matrix that you get by typing

```
IdentityMatrix[4]
```

How do I convert the above to the regular matrix? I tried using Flatten but it did not seem to work.

Comment: Try `ArrayFlatten`. Just apply it to what you've made, and it will become the identity matrix.

Comment: @march not quite. Indeed [`ArrayFlatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html) is the command but the ordering of the indices does not give `IdentityMatrix[4] `

Comment: How about `KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[2], IdentityMatrix[2]]`?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ I wanted to know how to construct a general matrix like that as I wanted to express Permutation matrix $\delta_{il}\delta_{j,k}$ using the similar form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command you want is [`ArrayFlatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html)

You also have to be careful with your indices.

Check the difference between this -took it directly from the OP and applied [`ArrayFlatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html)

```
ArrayFlatten[
 Table[KroneckerDelta[i, l] KroneckerDelta[k, j], {i, 2}, {j, 2}, {k, 
   2}, {l, 2}]]

% // MatrixForm
```

> [image: deltanot]

and this

```
ArrayFlatten[
 Table[KroneckerDelta[i, j] KroneckerDelta[k, l], {i, 2}, {j, 2}, {k, 
   2}, {l, 2}]]

% // MatrixForm
```

> [image: delta]

Comment: Thank you. Sorry the indices were typed incorrectly.

Comment: @user824530 glad I was able to help. No reason for apologies, I just pointed it out because I did not know if it was a typo or an honest mistake. :)